# Where does the writeLog function write to in dolphindb? Where to find the log file for the writeLog function?

Tags: dolphindb

Where does the writeLog function write to in dolphindb?
Where to find the log file for the writeLog function?

Answer (score 0):

Record the running log of the current node. If the above function is executed on the node named node1, the running log of node1 can be found on the server where the node is located, and the log file can be queried. Linux executes as follows:

```
grep "test" node1.log
```